# What's the parametrization for this set $z^2 = x^2+y^2$?

Tags: manifolds, surfaces, parametrization

Given $M = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 | \quad z^2 = x^2+y^2, \quad 1<z<2\}$.

What's the parametrization?

Is it $\left(\begin{array}{cc} x \\ y \\ \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\end{array}\right), \quad \text{where} \quad [x,y] \in \left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}},\sqrt{2}\right)$ ?

Comment: I would go with $x = r\cos \theta, y =r\sin \theta, z = r$

Comment: Yea, I recognized $\left(\begin{array}{cc} r\,\cos(\varphi) \\ r\, \sin(\varphi) \\ r \end{array}\right)$ where $r \in (1,2) \quad \varphi \in (0,2\pi)$ looks more uniform.

Comment: The question is, if cartesian presentation is possible

Comment: $x= x, y = y, z = \sqrt {x^2 + y^2}$ with $y\in [-\sqrt {4-x^2}, \sqrt {4-x^2}]$ and $x\in [-2,-1)\cup (1,2]$ or $y\in [-\sqrt {4-x^2}, -\sqrt {1-x^2}] \cup [\sqrt {1-x^2},\sqrt {4-x^2}]$ and $x\in[-1,1]$